# How to solve TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'

Tags: html, angularjs

When i include WYSIWYG editor in Html at that time. i got this error and i also include all the js file i needed.

**xyz.html**

```
<html>
<head>

    <script src="js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/angular/textAngular.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/angular/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div text-angular ng-model="htmlcontent" name="htmlVariable"></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

**Anglar.js module**

```
var myapp = angular.module('angularProject', ['textAngular'])
```

The error occured is as follows.

```
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'
    at link (http://localhost/englishPT/web/app/js/angular/textAngular.min.js:1:11164)
    at j (http://localhost/englishPT/web/app/js/angular/angular.min.js:43:458)
    at e (http://localhost/englishPT/web/app/js/angular/angular.min.js:39:248)
    at http://localhost/englishPT/web/app/js/angular/angular.min.js:38:312
    at link (http://localhost/englishPT/web/app/js/angular/textAngular.min.js:1:8160)
    at j (http://localhost/englishPT/web/app/js/angular/angular.min.js:43:458)
    at e (http://localhost/englishPT/web/app/js/angular/angular.min.js:39:248)
    at e (http://localhost/englishPT/web/app/js/angular/angular.min.js:39:265)
    at http://localhost/englishPT/web/app/js/angular/angular.min.js:38:312
    at updateView (http://localhost/englishPT/web/app/js/angular/angular-ui-router.js:1320:11) <div contenteditable="true" ng-hide="showHtml" ta-bind="text" ng-model="text" class="ng-isolate-scope ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid"> angular.min.js:62
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'
    at link (http://localhost/englishPT/web/app/js/angular/textAngular.min.js:1:8435)
    at j (http://localhost/englishPT/web/app/js/angular/angular.min.js:43:458)
    at e (http://localhost/englishPT/web/app/js/angular/angular.min.js:39:248)
    at e (http://localhost/englishPT/web/app/js/angular/angular.min.js:39:265)
    at http://localhost/englishPT/web/app/js/angular/angular.min.js:38:312
    at updateView (http://localhost/englishPT/web/app/js/angular/angular-ui-router.js:1320:11)
    at http://localhost/englishPT/web/app/js/angular/angular-ui-router.js:1285:9
    at j (http://localhost/englishPT/web/app/js/angular/angular.min.js:43:458)
    at e (http://localhost/englishPT/web/app/js/angular/angular.min.js:39:116)
    at http://localhost/englishPT/web/app/js/angular/angular.min.js:38:312 <text-angular ng-model="htmlcontent" name="htmlVariable" class="ng-isolate-scope ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid ta-root">
```

Comment: What's your AngularJS version? `element.on` is available on newer version.

Comment: it might also be easier to debug if you use the non minified version of angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your versions of angular.js and angular-sanitize.js compatible
(etc.  AngularJS v1.2.10 and Angular-Sanitize v1.2.11 will play together)

Answer (score 0):

In other cases, this also could happen if you are using an incompatible version of jQuery along AngularJS.

From the [AngularJS FAQ](http://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq):

> Does Angular use the jQuery library?
>
> Yes, Angular can use jQuery if it's present in your app when the application is being bootstrapped. If jQuery is not present in your script path, Angular falls back to its own implementation of the subset of jQuery that we call jQLite.
>
> **Due to a change to use on()/off() rather than bind()/unbind(), Angular 1.2 only operates with jQuery 1.7.1 or above.**